# css - @font-face failed cross-origin request. Resource access is restricted.

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, webfonts, font-awesome

I am using the latest version of FontAwesome like this:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <!--[if IE 7]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome-ie7.min.css">
    <![endif]-->
```

It works fine in Chrome, FireFox and Safari, but when I go to Internet Explorer 10 (Older versions has the same issue), I see this error:

```
CSS3117: @font-face failed cross-origin request. Resource access is restricted. 
fontawesome-webfont.eot
CSS3117: @font-face failed cross-origin request. Resource access is restricted. 
fontawesome-webfont.woff
```

I have tried to add the FileMatch to my .htaccess file, but that didn't do the trick.

I thought that using the CSS files from FontAwesomes CDN, eliminated IE errors..

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should download and host font-awesome on your server and call it from there

Comment: this is not really a solution as CDNs for fonts are pretty common

Comment: So what is your solution?

Comment: To add a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` http header to the response and then it should work. Though at closer reading if it is a CDN out of your control then do as you say, though I find it odd that font awesome wouldn't be doing that already!

Comment: @DominicTobias I have Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * added to my http header, it resolves the issue on FireFox but not on IE11...?

Comment: @Noz Are you sure you are not adding this header more than once? It can cause problems in some browsers

Comment: @DominicTobias I have multiple CORSRules if thats what you mean, but each only has one AllowedHeader directive defined.

Comment: @Dimitris Borbotsialos I'm having the same issue with google-fonts? Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add the line below in your .htaccess:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```